# KeystoneJs application is failing on server start - "node keystonejs"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, keystonejs

I am new to keystonejs and trying to create very first hello world application in keystonejs.
I installed all the dependencies on my local (nodejs and mongoDB). And I have already started my mongoDB server.

but when I am trying to start keystonejs with "node keystonejs", getting below errors. Please suggest what might be the issue.
Thanks a lot.

```
------------------------------------------------
Mongo Error:

[Error: connection closed]
D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-project\node_modules\keystone\lib\cor
e\mount.js:587
                        throw new Error('KeystoneJS (' + keystone.get('name') +
') failed to start'
                              ^
Error: KeystoneJS (helloworld) failed to start
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-
project\node_modules\keystone\lib\core\mount.js:587:10)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.error (D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keys
tone-project\node_modules\keystone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:389:8
)
    at D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-project\node_modules\keystone\
node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:416:14
    at D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-project\node_modules\keystone\
node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:57:21
    at D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-project\node_modules\keystone\
node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:286:18
    at D:\Neha Masters\3D internship\CMS-Keystone-project\node_modules\keystone\
node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:365:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

At mongoDB console I can see below errors-

```
2015-08-26T14:37:59.425-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util
\net\message_server_port.cpp(232)              mongo::PortMessageServer::handleI
ncomingMsg+0x573
2015-08-26T14:37:59.426-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1] mongod.exe    ...\src\third_part
y\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(185)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thr
ead_start_function+0x21
2015-08-26T14:37:59.426-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1] MSVCR120.dll
                                               beginthreadex+0x107
2015-08-26T14:37:59.426-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1] MSVCR120.dll
                                               endthreadex+0x192
2015-08-26T14:37:59.427-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1] kernel32.dll
                                               BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
2015-08-26T14:37:59.428-0700 I CONTROL  [conn1]
2015-08-26T14:37:59.429-0700 I NETWORK  [conn1] AssertionException handling requ
est, closing client connection: 10307 Client Error: bad object in message: bson
length doesn't match what we found in object with unknown _id
2015-08-26T14:37:59.435-0700 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:54577 (
3 connections now open)
2015-08-26T14:37:59.435-0700 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:54578 (
3 connections now open)
2015-08-26T14:37:59.436-0700 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:54579 (
3 connections now open)
2015-08-26T14:37:59.436-0700 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:54580 (
2 connections now open)
```

Comment: windows support is iffy. Are you sure mongodb is correctly configured?

Comment: Please mark an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start mongod?

I always run

```
mongod
```

then

```
mongo db
```

then start keystone with nodemon

```
nodemon keystone
```

That being said your keystone error is characteristic of an improper database connection.